# How can I trace what AngularJS is doing when I click a link?

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple link in an app that opens an absolute page and it's target is blank. When i click it the page does open up in a new window but my app goes blank. I'm trying to track down in angular what's happening. What's the best way to trace this through?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google Chrome, one way to do this is to get [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) Developer tools extension.